# Play audio button is not working

Tags: android, button, audio, media-player

I have a layout in which there's a 'Listen' button, so that if I press it, it will play certain audios by random (they have been assigned ids, but let's not worry about that) in my phone. However, when I click on the button, nothing plays, although the toast shows up with the correct filename.

Can someone please take a look and tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks! >_<

```
Button btnListen= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonListen);
String recR = getIntent().getStringExtra("dataR"); //importing random filename
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName = "/rec" + recR  + ".mp3"; 
//filename starts with rec, so itll usually be like recwoof.mp3 or rectest.mp3 etc

btnListen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "show "+ mFileName + " now",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
     mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
         mPlayer.prepare();
         mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("meh log", "prepare() failed");
    }
        }
```

Comment: Is there an IOException that gets thrown?

Comment: I... urm... I don't know what that means >_< oh wait. "prepare () failed" I saw that...

Comment: The try and catch statement you have catches an IOException. Does that  `Log.e("meh log", "prepare() failed");` show in your logcat?

Comment: I posted a link in my answer, which you can check out and find many answers to your upcoming questions, including this one, check it out.

Comment: Hi, it's alright already, thank you. Problem solved :)

Comment: No worries glad we could help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to concatenate the String `mFileName`

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName += "/rec" + recR  + ".mp3";
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is here:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName = "/rec" + recR  + ".mp3";
```

change to:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/rec" + recR  + ".mp3";
```

You will get more info in **[LogCat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)**

Change this :

```
 } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("meh log", "prepare() failed");
 }
```

to:

```
 } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Fuchsia Player", e.getMessage());
 }
```

So in your LogCat you can find the tag "Fuchsia Player" and more info about the exception.

Comment: I tried Nambi's solution and it works, thank you very much all the same! I presume this also works the same way?

Comment: is the same but here you just need only one line and is more secure because you will concatenate the string again and the path will be incorrect, be careful using "+=" :P

Comment: And please try to use the LogCat, most of the questions will be solved easily just looking into the messages provided by the LogCat ;)

Answer (score 2):

Consider taking a look here: [Android player](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)
He provides a throughout tutorial with the code how to create a music player, with of course the button that you are asking!!

Comment: The problem has been solved with Nambi's solution. Thank you all the same^^